# Android tablet screen sizes and layout folders for it

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I have mobile app and I'm starting to implement the tablet version.

But I have small problem: Design of mobile app version is better for 7" (ex Nexus 7) devices than the tablet design.

So I would like to implement tablet design for devices >7".

I know that Nexus 7 using `layout-sw600dp` layout folder, and I guess I need to implement UI for tablet starting from `layout-sw720dp` layout folder. Is it good idea ? Or there is another folder after `layout-sw600dp`.

If there are devices which are > 7" and layout folder is 'layout-sw600dp' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a responsive UI in android is a long story to tell. You need to chose:

> > when to change
> >
> > what to change

You can read this article : [Article Link](https://medium.com/google-developers/building-a-responsive-ui-in-android-7dc7e4efcbb3#.yc7tghsbf)

Answer (score 0):

It is not good practice to create different layout folders for different density devices. You should create a common layout that should be managed by different dimensions(means dimens.xml) for different density devices.

```
values-hdpi
   --->dimens.xml
values-mdpi
   --->dimens.xml
values-xhdpi
   --->dimens.xml
values-xxhdpi
   --->dimens.xml
values-xxxhdpi
   --->dimens.xml
values-sw480dp
   --->dimens.xml
values-sw600dp
   --->dimens.xml
values-sw720dp
   --->dimens.xml
```